# Enforce destruction order

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have two C++ classes, which for example assume are

```
class A
{
};

class B
{
};
```

I then wrap these with SWIG to create Python bindings

```
%include "A.h"
%include "B.h"
...etc
```

On the Python side, I use these as

```
a = A()
b = B()
```

I would like to somehow enforce that the destruction order therefore be `~B()` then `~A()`. If they are called in the other order `~B()` will segfault due to essentially dangling pointers.

Is there any way I can modify the SWIG interface to enforce the destruction of `B` first? Like only allow its usage in a context manager? Add a reference to an `A` object? Take an `A` argument in `B`'s constructor and add increment its reference count?

Comment: If your class design requires that objects be destructed in a particular order then your class design is wrong.

Comment: What happens if you create a `B` without an `A` or an `A` without a `B`? You should design your classes so things like this can't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure what Ulrich meant by a context manager so this may be the same idea. Create a new class AB, have AB handle the creation and destruction of A and B in C++ code. Only pass an AB into Python.

Comment: @john Which may be true or false but is probably useless advice in general.

Comment: @ZanLynx: The term "context manager" is a Python term. Basically, it guarantees that a piece of code is framed by two operations, one on entry and one on exit, very similar to e.g. a `scoped_lock` that uses RAII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Python doesn't guarantee destruction order. If you need something like C++'s RAII, use a context manager for that.

Secondly, if your C++ code segfaults, that's your C++ code's fault. In general, you should aim for code that doesn't even compile if not used properly. Here, I'd suggest you pass a `shared_ptr<A>` into the `B` to make sure that the `A` isn't destroyed before the `B`.

Comment: I'd like to try your second suggestion, but I think I'm stuck on the details. I can add a `std::shared_ptr<A>` to `B`'s constructor, but in the above Python code, when I say `a = A()` if I then pass that object to the next object as `b = B(a)` how would Python know that `a` is a `shared_ptr` and not to delete it since `b` now also has partial ownership of it?

Comment: You could leave that to Python, which will make sure that the objects are kept alive as long as they are still referenced somewhere.